# Oauthd instance shows "internalError" and not using "response_type=token"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

Key manager setup for my Doorkeeper based provider in oauth is to use client-side(token), which I believe it should use `response_type=token` when request to `/oauth/authorize` on provider. But it use `response_type=code` instead.

And Oauthd generate following error when I click `Try auth` button:

Internal error {
  "body": {
    "code": "InternalError"
  }
}

Please help. Thanks